# How to add pointer to pointer array in C

Tags: arrays, c, null, addition, execve

I am trying to create a simple shell in C. I am having issues with using the execve() function. So I have my arguments declared as char *cmdargs[10]; which holds the arguments such as -a or -l. However, it does not work with my execute function and I assume that because this array does not have the command as the first argument, and I am not sure how to add the command to the first of the array.
Assuming now the array is

```
cmdargs[] = {"-a", "-l", NULL};
```

I want to the array to be
`cmdargs[] = {"ls", "-a", "-l", NULL};`
However, the command is declare as a pointer: char *cmd;
so how I can add this pointer to the beginning of my array.

Comment: If the array is defined as `char *cmdargs[] = { "-a", "-l", NULL }`, then you simply don't have space to prepend the `"ls"`; you'll need to use a different array.  A [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: nvm, I did it this way: for (int r = size-1; r >= 0; r--)
                        {
                          cmdargs[r + 1] = cmdargs[r];
                        }
                      cmdargs[0] = cmd;

Comment: if you're using an array with initialized values, why not use `execle()` instead? `execve()` is usually used when you're creating the array dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do if your array is *cmdargs[] = {"-a", "-l", NULL};

I used execv here for simplicity: execve ask for a null terminated env array as last argument

```
int main() {
    char *cmdargs[] = { "-a", "-l", NULL};

    int i = 0;
    while (cmdargs[i++])
        ;
//allocation of the size of a new array with one extra room
    char **tmp = malloc( sizeof(cmdargs) * ++i );
//add the path you need
    *tmp = "/bin/ls";
//null the end
    tmp[i] = NULL;
//copy what was on the previous
    i = -1;
    while (cmdargs[++i])
        tmp[i + 1] = cmdargs[i];
//use it..
    execv(tmp[0], tmp + 1);
}
```

Comment: soooo all I had to do is simply add one to my array. LMAAAAAAAAAAAAO I spent 5 hours trying to fix this.

Comment: Well yes If you can do like this otherwise copy it in a new one using malloc this is what I was editing... If it's ok like that ? I leave it as it is...

Comment: I just edited so it reply to your exact question :)